# Using `interface I { foo: string; bar: number; }` as namespace `(can: I.foo)`?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Given a simple interface like:

```
interface IHaz {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}
```

What's the best way of enabling:

```
export const f = (a: typeof IHaz.foo, b: typeof IHaz.bar) => {};
```

(my actual code has more complex interfaces as types for `foo`/`bar`; and my `f` is specialised to handle a subset of `IHaz`… so I don't want to separate it into multiple `interface`s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is unique to typescript I think - it uses so-called indexed access types for that

```
export const f = (a: IHaz['foo'], b: IHaz['bar']) => {};
```

The [documentation says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

> ...  operator is T[K], the indexed access operator. Here, the type
>   syntax reflects the expression syntax. That means that person['name']
>   has the type Person['name'] — which in our example is just string.